# Watin error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: domContainer

Tags: c#, watin

I'm getting the following error:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: domContainer

In this specific line of my program:

```
if (firstBrowser.Buttons.Count > 0)
```

firstBrowser is an IE object.

Whats strange is that im creating few threads and in each thread im opening IE object and loading similar URL, but I'm getting this error only in 1 or 2 from them.

**EDIT:** 
This is the code before the line where i got the error:

```
var firstBrowser = new IE()
firstBrowser.GoTo(slot_url);
firstBrowser.BringToFront();
Console.WriteLine("browser #" + thread_index + " was loaded");
```

**SOLUTION:**

I have checked the value of the domContainer before the errored line, and if the value is null I loaded the page again:

```
if (firstBrowser.DomContainer == null)
      firstBrowser.GoTo(slot_url);
if (firstBrowser.Buttons.Count > 0)
 {
   *
   *
   *
 }
```

Comment: `firstBrowser is an IE object`, of what `Type` is it?

Comment: var firstBrowser = new WatiN.Core.IE();

Answer (score 0):

Why not use like this:

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
  }
}
```

Comment: var firstBrowser = new WatiN.Core.IE();

Comment: your IE constructor is empty.

Answer (score 0):

your constructor is empty, no address is given.

```
 var firstBrowser = new WatiN.Core.IE();
```

Comment: Try use the using block so that the object is desposed propertly.

Comment: I have changed the code to use the using block and the problem is still exist.